# Blood Type/Punnett Square

Tags: general-biology

Male: Blood type O   (Genotype written as: i^o i^o since O allele is recessive to the A and B alleles).
Female: Blood type AB

Draw a punnett square to show all of the possible offspring.

I got Ai^o,  Ai^o,  Bi^o,  Bi^o)

What are the possible phenotypes for the children?

I got...

Phenotypes: Blood type A
            Blood type B

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Do you want someone to clarify the answers you got?

Comment: yes please @iro

Answer (score 4):

as far as simple punnet square is concerned your answer is correct.

[image]

Comment: A noble answer +1